# How can I check if anything is in an ArrayList

Tags: java

So I want to check if anything exists in an array list in an if statement. So instead of

```
MyArrayList.Contains("blah");
```

I want something that checks if ANYTHING is in it.

EDIT!:
Found it out!
Thanks for all the help!
Answer:
MyArrayList.isEmpty(){
}

THANKS!

Comment: How about checking size of list?

Comment: @Pshemo How about using the proper method?

Comment: @LutzHorn Yep, this works too (since it is using `size` :D)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should to check if your ArrayList is not empty.

You can get achieve this like this code snippet:

```
if (!arrayList.isEmpty()) {
//your code here...
}
```

Answer (score 8):

[`List.isEmpty()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#isEmpty%28%29) is what you are looking for. Refer the docs.

Comment: Even better than the first one! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Just check the size of the list. If it's not zero, then there is something in it...

```
if(arrayList.size() != 0) {
//there is something in the list
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I thought it would be something like that! Such a quick response as well!

Answer (score 1):

[List.isEmpty()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#isEmpty%28%29):

```
if (! list.isEmpty()) {
  // do something
}
```

[List.size()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#size%28%29):

```
if (list.size() > 0) {
  // do something
}
```

Also, keep in mind that most of the time it's preferable to program against the interface (in this case, `List`) rather than the concrete class (e.g., `ArrayList`, `LinkedList`)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it simply like this using `.isEmpty()`:

```
if(!myArrayList.isEmpty()){
    //if your array list has something in it
}
```

and,

```
if(myArrayList.isEmpty()){
    //if your array list has nothing in it
}
```